# Impression format in php

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I try to generate a report with the PHP FPDF library, I have a table called "proveedores" and another "retensiones",

```
SELECT id_proveedor, `proveedores`,` rfc`, `direccion`,` curp` FROM `proveedores`
SELECT id_retensiones, `tua`,` ciclo`, `cxl`,` f_elaboracion`, `importe`,` isr`, `iva`,` proveedores`, `concepto`,` periodo` FROM `retensiones`
```

I want it to be written in the following format:
In the first line "rfc", "curp" and "proveedores" in the table "proveedores"
In the following lines the records that are the same as the provider of the table "retensiones"
Similar to this

```
CURP RFC PROVEEDOR1
registro 1----------------------------
registro 2--------------------------
registro 3---------------------------
CURP RFC PROVEEDOR2
registro 1----------------------------
registro 2--------------------------
registro 3---------------------------
registro 4-------------------------
registro 5-------------------------
CURP RFC PROVEEDOR3
registro 1----------------------------
registro 2--------------------------
..............
..........
...
```

I've tried with two "FOR" or "WHILE", but it has not worked for me, or I do not know if I'm doing it right

Sorry for my english, I'm not very good and I use the translator
Mucash Thanks